# Cheap, mobile server

Tags: server, mobile-workstation

I'm looking for some cheap and mobile computer. The PC will be a server, so it needs to be able to connect to the Internet (preferably by wifi as well as ethernet), and connect to the monitor.

Other than that, priorities are processing power, energy usage and price.

I was thinking of a Raspberry Pi, but I've heard somewhere that there are often better/cheaper alternatives. What would you recommend for me?

The price cap is ~40$

Comment: What sort of things will you be doing with the computer?  You say that processing power is a priority, but the Pi is about as *low*-power as you can get while still being a remotely viable server.

Comment: @Mark I misphrased it; these are the things that I want to be the best in the range, meaning that I want the best machine for the lowest price(but saying it like this sounds stupid). It will run some web server or other software. It doesn't need to be high-tech, but the faster, the better. I'll add price range to the post.

Answer (score 1):

There's pretty few options that are cheaper than the rpi. Quite frankly, there's nothing with the same *support* and for the moment the same power as an rpi 3, at that sort of price range. Off the top of my head odroid's lower end stuff's at the same price point, and I've considered them (and ended up spending a fair bit more and getting a NUC, for other reasons).

They have nowhere near the same options for OSes but they have two models with the same price point and roughly similar performance. *Unlike* the RPI models, they have gigabit ethernet.

I'd take a look at the odroid c1+ or c2.

The c1+ has

```
Amlogic ARM® Cortex®-A5(ARMv7) 1.5Ghz quad core CPUs 
* Mali™-450 MP2 GPU (OpenGL ES 2.0/1.1 enabled for Linux and Android)
* 1Gbyte DDR3 SDRAM
* Gigabit Ethernet
```

And the c2 has

```
* Amlogic ARM® Cortex®-A53(ARMv8) 2Ghz quad core CPUs 
* Mali™-450 GPU (3 Pixel-processors + 2 Vertex shader processors)
* 2Gbyte DDR3 SDRAM
* Gigabit Ethernet
* HDMI 2.0 4K/60Hz display
* H.265 4K/60FPS and H.264 4K/30FPS capable VPU
```

And the c2 is getting released in april

Reviews seem [positive](http://www.androidauthority.com/odroid-c1-review-597468/), and the c1 compares well to a rpi2

Comment: btw. this hasn't to be ARM.

Comment: There's NOTHING fits the requirements that's x86